# More efficient way to aggregate results in one table when grouping by different columns in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table like:

```
id    category    subcategory     value0    value1    value2
1     1           1               100       324       940
1     1           2               222       404       1000
1     2           3               333       304       293
1     2           3               490       490       400
1     3           2               140       400       499
```

I want to calculate `AVG(value0)` based on only `id, category` and `AVG(value1)`, `AVG(value2)` based on `id, category, subcategory`.

Right now, I'm calculating this by:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id
  , category
  , sub-category
  , AVG(value0) OVER (PARTITION BY id, category)
  , AVG(value1) OVER (PARTITION BY id, category, subcategory)
  , AVG(value2) OVER (PARTITION BY id, category, subcategory)
FROM my_table
```

I'm using the above code in a longer query but it's resulting in this error, so I was hoping to better optimize it by not using window functions: `Resources exceeded during query execution. The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 133% of limit. Top memory consumer: OVER() clauses: 100%.`

I was thinking something like:

```
SELECT 
    id
  , category
  , subcategory
  , AVG(value1)
  , AVG(value2)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

But I'm unsure of how to tie in my `AVG(value0)` results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `LEFT JOIN` the results of the two separate aggregation queries, using the two columns `id` and `category`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT 
  id,
  category,
  subcategory,
  AVG(value1) AS avgvalue1,
  AVG(value2) AS avgvalue2
FROM your_table
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3)

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT 
  id,
  category,
  AVG(value0) AS avgvalue0
FROM your_table
GROUP BY 1, 2)

USING (id, category)
```